# Scrapy login and retry in case of captcha

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

am working on a spider, which needs to login first and parse list of orders. The site am trying to scrapy uses captcha occasionally after a successful login, they either ask for captcha only or login again with captcha details.

The spider below works as expected, it tried to login and in `check_login_response` method, am checking if the login is successful, if not am invoking `self.login()` again. The spider will usually be given a list of order URLS, they are loaded to start_urls at run time in `__init___` method.

What's happening now, is that the spider executes and stops in `parse_page` method, I can see the urls printed in the this line `log.msg('request %s' % url)`. But the spider never executes the parse method with the list of start_urls.

The problem only occurs when the retry for captcha happens, on normal login scenario it works well and parse method is invoked..

Any advise please?

P.S I tried both Spider and CrawlSpider classes and I got same result

```
class SomeCrawlSpider(CrawlSpider):
    """ SomeSpider
    """
    name = 'some_order_details'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = []
    login_url = 'https://www.exmaple.com/login/'
    login_attempts = 0

    def __init__(self, qwargs, *args, **kwargs):
        # starting Scrapy logging
        self.start_urls = qwargs.get('order_details_urls')
        super(SomeCrawlSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def start_requests(self):
        """ start_requests
        @return:
        """
        log.msg('starting requests')
        return self.init_request()

    def init_request(self):
        """ init_request
        @return: list
        """
        log.msg('init requests')
        return [Request(url=self.login_url, callback=self.login)]

    def check_login_response(self, response):
        """ check if response is logged in
        @param response:
        @return:
        """
        log.msg('check requests')

        # first we check if we get the captcha page again
        if "Type the characters you see in this image" in response.body_as_unicode() \
                or "What is your e-mail address?" in response.body_as_unicode():
            return self.login(response)

        return self.parse_page(response)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        """ parse_page
        @param response:
        @return:
        """
        self.login_attempts += 1
        if "Your Orders" in response.body_as_unicode():
            log.msg('user is logged in')
            self.credentials.last_used_at = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
            self.credentials.save()
            for url in self.start_urls:
                log.msg('request %s' % url)
                yield self.make_requests_from_url(url)

        yield OrderItem(auth_failed=True)

    def login(self, response):
        """ login
        @param response:
        @return:
        """
        # check the existence of credentials:
        if not any([self.credentials, self.credentials.username, self.credentials.password]):
            log.msg('Credentials is not set correctly')
            return OrderItem(auth_failed=True)

        log.msg('Trying to login')

        # check if response is captcha
        if "Type the characters you see in this image" in response.body_as_unicode():
            # captcha page before login
            log.msg('Captcha detected and guessing pass through')
            self.crawler.engine.pause()
            captcha = select_captcha_from_image(response)
            self.crawler.engine.unpause()
            log.msg('captcha detected: %s' % str(captcha))
            if not captcha:
                # if captcha returns Null
                log.msg('captcha was not decoded')
                raise OrderDetailsNoCaptchaException

            if "What is your e-mail address?" in response.body_as_unicode():
                log.msg('logging in via form: captcha + credentials')
                return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                                 formdata={'guess': str(captcha),
                                                           'email': 'XXXX',
                                                           'password': 'XXXX'},
                                                 callback=self.check_login_response)
            else:
                log.msg('posting captcha')
                return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                                 formdata={'field-keywords': str(captcha)},
                                                 callback=self.check_login_response)

        if 'What is your e-mail address?' in response.body_as_unicode():
            log.msg('logging in via form')
            return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                             formdata={'email': 'XXX',
                                                       'password': 'XXXX'},
                                             callback=self.check_login_response)
        return OrderItem(auth_failed=True)

    def parse(self, response):
        """ this function returns
        @param response: Response Object
        @return: Dictionary
        """
        log.msg('Parsing items invoked')
        # here i parse response to item and yeild back below
        yield OrderItem(**item)
```

*EDIT (Adding console output)*

This is case when captcha is detected

```
    [2014-12-15 18:10:01,972: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: product.parse_messages_to_purchases[72927959-35e1-4053-917b-f25de318faf7]
[2014-12-15 18:10:03,327: WARNING/Worker-5] 2014-12-15 18:10:03-0600 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: LogStats, CloseSpider, SpiderState
[2014-12-15 18:10:04,331: WARNING/Worker-5] 2014-12-15 18:10:04-0600 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, HttpProxyMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
[2014-12-15 18:10:04,331: WARNING/Worker-5] 2014-12-15 18:10:04-0600 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
[2014-12-15 18:10:04,332: WARNING/Worker-5] 2014-12-15 18:10:04-0600 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: PurchaseWriterPipeline
[2014-12-15 18:10:04,341: WARNING/ProductCrawlerScript-5:1] 2014-12-15 18:10:04-0600 [scrapy] INFO: starting requests
[2014-12-15 18:10:04,342: WARNING/ProductCrawlerScript-5:1] 2014-12-15 18:10:04-0600 [scrapy] INFO: init requests
[2014-12-15 18:10:04,343: WARNING/ProductCrawlerScript-5:1] 2014-12-15 18:10:04-0600 [some_order_details] INFO: Spider opened
[2014-12-15 18:10:04,346: WARNING/ProductCrawlerScript-5:1] 2014-12-15 18:10:04-0600 [some_order_details] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
/Users/mo/Projects/pythonic/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py:159: DeprecationWarning: <scrapy.core.downloader.contextfactory.ScrapyClientContextFactory instance at 0x113120908> was passed as the HTTPS policy for an Agent, but it does not provide IPolicyForHTTPS.  Since Twisted 14.0, you must pass a provider of IPolicyForHTTPS.
  connectTimeout=timeout, bindAddress=bindaddress, pool=self._pool)

[2014-12-15 18:10:04,351: WARNING/ProductCrawlerScript-5:1] /Users/mo/Projects/pythonic/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py:159: DeprecationWarning: <scrapy.core.downloader.contextfactory.ScrapyClientContextFactory instance at 0x113120908> was passed as the HTTPS policy for an Agent, but it does not provide IPolicyForHTTPS.  Since Twisted 14.0, you must pass a provider of IPolicyForHTTPS.
  connectTimeout=timeout, bindAddress=bindaddress, pool=self._pool)

[2014-12-15 18:10:06,063: WARNING/ProductCrawlerScript-5:1] 2014-12-15 18:10:06-0600 [scrapy] INFO: Trying to login
[2014-12-15 18:10:06,063: WARNING/ProductCrawlerScript-5:1] 2014-12-15 18:10:06-0600 [scrapy] INFO: logging in via form
[2014-12-15 18:10:06,500: WARNING/ProductCrawlerScript-5:1] 2014-12-15 18:10:06-0600 [scrapy] INFO: check requests
[2014-12-15 18:10:06,500: WARNING/ProductCrawlerScript-5:1] 2014-12-15 18:10:06-0600 [scrapy] INFO: Trying to login
[2014-12-15 18:10:06,500: WARNING/ProductCrawlerScript-5:1] 2014-12-15 18:10:06-0600 [scrapy] INFO: Captcha detected and guessing pass through
[2014-12-15 18:10:22,701: WARNING/ProductCrawlerScript-5:1] 2014-12-15 18:10:22-0600 [scrapy] INFO: captcha detected: cpm6jf
[2014-12-15 18:10:22,701: WARNING/ProductCrawlerScript-5:1] 2014-12-15 18:10:22-0600 [scrapy] INFO: logging in via form: captcha + credentials
[2014-12-15 18:10:25,598: WARNING/ProductCrawlerScript-5:1] 2014-12-15 18:10:25-0600 [scrapy] INFO: check requests
[2014-12-15 18:10:25,601: WARNING/ProductCrawlerScript-5:1] 2014-12-15 18:10:25-0600 [scrapy] INFO: user is logged in
[2014-12-15 18:10:25,621: WARNING/ProductCrawlerScript-5:1] 2014-12-15 18:10:25-0600 [scrapy] INFO: request https://www.some.com/gp/css/summary/edit.html?ie=UTF8&orderID=111-1260932-6725022&ref_=oh_aui_or_o02_&
[2014-12-15 18:10:25,624: WARNING/ProductCrawlerScript-5:1] 2014-12-15 18:10:25-0600 [some_order_details] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
[2014-12-15 18:10:25,625: WARNING/ProductCrawlerScript-5:1] 2014-12-15 18:10:25-0600 [some_order_details] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 7000,
     'downloader/request_count': 6,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 4,
     'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 2,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 65353,
     'downloader/response_count': 6,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 3,
     'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
     'downloader/response_status_count/302': 2,
     'request_depth_max': 2,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 6,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 6,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 6,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 6}
[2014-12-15 18:10:25,625: WARNING/ProductCrawlerScript-5:1] 2014-12-15 18:10:25-0600 [some_order_details] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
[2014-12-15 18:10:25,639: INFO/MainProcess] Task product.parse_messages_to_purchases[72927959-35e1-4053-917b-f25de318faf7] succeeded in 23.665501486s: u'Message with id 16650 completed parsing'
```

and this is case where there is no captcha

```
[2014-12-15 18:10:43,229: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: product.parse_messages_to_purchases[c06bafdc-0f39-4e43-8f74-ad899f30e799]
[2014-12-15 18:10:44,557: WARNING/Worker-1] 2014-12-15 18:10:44-0600 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: LogStats, CloseSpider, SpiderState
[2014-12-15 18:10:45,560: ERROR/Worker-1] Unable to read instance data, giving up
[2014-12-15 18:10:45,561: WARNING/Worker-1] 2014-12-15 18:10:45-0600 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, HttpProxyMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
[2014-12-15 18:10:45,561: WARNING/Worker-1] 2014-12-15 18:10:45-0600 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
[2014-12-15 18:10:45,561: WARNING/Worker-1] 2014-12-15 18:10:45-0600 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: PurchaseWriterPipeline
[2014-12-15 18:10:45,570: WARNING/ProductCrawlerScript-1:1] 2014-12-15 18:10:45-0600 [scrapy] INFO: starting requests
[2014-12-15 18:10:45,570: WARNING/ProductCrawlerScript-1:1] 2014-12-15 18:10:45-0600 [scrapy] INFO: init requests
[2014-12-15 18:10:45,571: WARNING/ProductCrawlerScript-1:1] 2014-12-15 18:10:45-0600 [some_order_details] INFO: Spider opened
[2014-12-15 18:10:45,574: WARNING/ProductCrawlerScript-1:1] 2014-12-15 18:10:45-0600 [some_order_details] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
/Users/mo/Projects/pythonic/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py:159: DeprecationWarning: <scrapy.core.downloader.contextfactory.ScrapyClientContextFactory instance at 0x11311c3f8> was passed as the HTTPS policy for an Agent, but it does not provide IPolicyForHTTPS.  Since Twisted 14.0, you must pass a provider of IPolicyForHTTPS.
  connectTimeout=timeout, bindAddress=bindaddress, pool=self._pool)

[2014-12-15 18:10:45,580: WARNING/ProductCrawlerScript-1:1] /Users/mo/Projects/pythonic/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py:159: DeprecationWarning: <scrapy.core.downloader.contextfactory.ScrapyClientContextFactory instance at 0x11311c3f8> was passed as the HTTPS policy for an Agent, but it does not provide IPolicyForHTTPS.  Since Twisted 14.0, you must pass a provider of IPolicyForHTTPS.
  connectTimeout=timeout, bindAddress=bindaddress, pool=self._pool)

[2014-12-15 18:10:50,563: WARNING/ProductCrawlerScript-1:1] 2014-12-15 18:10:50-0600 [scrapy] INFO: Trying to login
[2014-12-15 18:10:50,563: WARNING/ProductCrawlerScript-1:1] 2014-12-15 18:10:50-0600 [scrapy] INFO: logging in via form
[2014-12-15 18:10:52,899: WARNING/ProductCrawlerScript-1:1] 2014-12-15 18:10:52-0600 [scrapy] INFO: check requests
[2014-12-15 18:10:52,904: WARNING/ProductCrawlerScript-1:1] 2014-12-15 18:10:52-0600 [scrapy] INFO: user is logged in
[2014-12-15 18:10:52,924: WARNING/ProductCrawlerScript-1:1] 2014-12-15 18:10:52-0600 [scrapy] INFO: request https://www.some.com/gp/css/summary/edit.html?ie=UTF8&orderID=111-1260932-6725022&ref_=oh_aui_or_o02_&
[2014-12-15 18:10:54,164: WARNING/ProductCrawlerScript-1:1] 2014-12-15 18:10:54-0600 [scrapy] INFO: Parsing items invoked
/Users/mo/Projects/pythonic/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:903: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Purchase.shipping_date received a naive datetime (2014-12-08 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)

[2014-12-15 18:10:54,191: WARNING/ProductCrawlerScript-1:1] /Users/mo/Projects/pythonic/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:903: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Purchase.shipping_date received a naive datetime (2014-12-08 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)

[2014-12-15 18:10:54,262: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: semantic.get_product_and_create[939f73f6-f5bd-4d31-8a1b-6544de37b7b2] eta:[2014-12-16 00:12:34.246354+00:00]
/Users/mo/Projects/pythonic/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:903: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Purchase.shipping_date received a naive datetime (2014-12-09 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)

[2014-12-15 18:10:54,268: WARNING/ProductCrawlerScript-1:1] /Users/mo/Projects/pythonic/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:903: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Purchase.shipping_date received a naive datetime (2014-12-09 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)

[2014-12-15 18:10:54,286: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: semantic.get_product_and_create[acae6d98-2769-4d27-bcaa-a30ded095e4a] eta:[2014-12-16 00:12:34.285050+00:00]
[2014-12-15 18:10:54,288: WARNING/ProductCrawlerScript-1:1] 2014-12-15 18:10:54-0600 [some_order_details] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
[2014-12-15 18:10:54,289: WARNING/ProductCrawlerScript-1:1] 2014-12-15 18:10:54-0600 [some_order_details] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 7527,
     'downloader/request_count': 6,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 5,
     'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 1,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 79284,
     'downloader/response_count': 6,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 3,
     'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
     'downloader/response_status_count/302': 2,
     'request_depth_max': 2,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 6,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 6,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 6,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 6}
[2014-12-15 18:10:54,290: WARNING/ProductCrawlerScript-1:1] 2014-12-15 18:10:54-0600 [some_order_details] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Hey @alecxe i just added the log console, any suggestions?

Comment: You mustn't override the `parse()` method when using `CrawlSpider`, or it won't work. `CrawlSpider` need this method for its internal magic.

Comment: @Lawrence but how come it works for the first scenario and not work for the second? parse was successfully called when captcha is not present, but when login redirect again.. parse was not invoked